# Missing information for Microsoft Academic Knowledge API

Tags: python, azure, service, azure-cognitive-services

I believe I have ran into a couple bugs in Microsoft's academic knowledge API. The first is when I run a search using the 'Conference Instance Entity' using the CalcHistogram method. I ran a search specifying the conference name and set a start date for anything beyond 2008. Below is my code (in python):

```
'expr': "And(Composite(PCS.CN = 'AAAI'),CISD>'2008')",
```

I specified the attributes to be returned to be the citation count (CC) and the start date of the conference (CISD). The problem is that for some reason, the results do not include anything from 2009.

```
{"attribute":"CISD",
"distinct_values":9,
"total_count":9,
"histogram":[
{"value":"2008-07-13","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2010-07-11","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2011-08-07","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2013-07-14","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2014-07-27","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2015-01-25","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2016-02-12","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2017-02-04","logprob":-25.000,"count":1},
{"value":"2018-02-14","logprob":-25.000,"count":1}]
}]
```

This is confusing because it has information for every other year. However, AAAI did have a conference in 2009 and API has information for it. When querying for a paper with the filters being the conference and year (AAAI and 2009 in this case), I get a full list of papers. Why is it that this year is excluded in conference instant search?

---

The second bug I have encountered is missing data for some papers. I am able to find the specific papers that I search for, but they are missing information on the conference or journal they were published through.

```
{
"expr":"Ti = 'decontamination of mutually contaminated models'",
"num_entities":1,
"histograms":[
{"attribute":"AA.AuN",
"distinct_values":2,
"total_count":2,
"histogram":[
{"value":"clayton scott","logprob":-21.161,"count":1},
{"value":"gilles blanchard","logprob":-21.161,"count":1}]
},
{"attribute":"J.JN",
"distinct_values":0,
"total_count":0,
"histogram":[]
},
{"attribute":"C.CN",
"distinct_values":0,
"total_count":0,
"histogram":[]
}]
}
```

Here I searched for a paper from the 2014 AISTATS (International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics) conference. I found this paper using the DBLP database and have included the link here:

http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/aistats/aistats2014.html

As you can see, the Microsoft API returns the correct authors for the paper, so it clearly has some information on it in its database. However, it includes no information on its conference or journal name.

A response would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance,

Sean

Comment: Maybe you have to post your findings to the creators of the API.

Comment: If you found a bug, you can report here: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/555931-academic-knowledge

Answer (score 3):

## First bug

We don't currently recognize AAAI 2009 as a discrete conference instance. The reason you can still find papers from AAAI 2009 is because we have the papers *published in AAAI 2009*, we just haven't linked them to a discrete conference instance. We do still link them to the AAAI series though, which is why the query "AAAI 2009" works (our query parser recognizes "AAAI" as the conference series and "2009" as a publication year).

## Second bug

For the paper [Decontamination of Mutually Contaminated Models](https://preview.academic.microsoft.com/#/detail/2172267025), we simply haven't managed to conflate it with either JMLR (Journal of Machine Learning Research) or with AISTATS (International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics). Actually, we currently don't even recognize AISTATS as a conference series.

I have raised both of these bugs with our team, and we will work to address them in one of our future data refreshes.

As an aside, the data in the Microsoft Academic Knowledge API is what's powering our [Microsoft Academic](https://preview.academic.microsoft.com/) site. I mention that as the site has a very convenient "Feedback" feature that makes reporting these type of data issues easy (and anonymous if you wish). I can assure you that we take these type of data bugs in our graph quite seriously and aim to have a quick turn around on fixing them.